# How does the 'with' statement work in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have been playing with [kivy](http://kivy.org), and I saw this:

```
    with self.canvas:
        Color(1, 1, 0)  # <--- no assignment
        d = 30.
        Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))  # <--- no assignment
```

I don't quite understand how it works. I was expecting to see something like:

```
    with self.canvas as c:
        c.color = Color(1, 1, 0)
        c.shape = Ellipse()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`with some_canvas` sets an internal Kivy variable to that canvas. When canvas instructions are created they check if that variable is set to a canvas, and if so they automatically add themselves to it.

If you want to trace through how this works you can find the context entry function [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx#L564), and the code that automatically adds instructions to a canvas when instantiated [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx#L56).

> I don't quite understand how it works. I was expecting to see something like:
>
> ```
> with self.canvas as c:
>     c.color = Color(1, 1, 0)
>     c.shape = Ellipse()
> ```

In this case the `with` context wouldn't really be doing anything. If you want to explicitly manipulate the canvas you can do it directly without a context manager, e.g. `self.canvas.add(Color(1, 1, 0))`.

That said, the way you've written this may indicate a misunderstanding: a canvas doesn't have a specific colour as you've indicated with `c.color`, rather it's a list of instructions to apply in order. There could be many Color instructions, with different numbers of other instructions (e.g. representing different shapes) in between.